# gson - How to compare JsonObjects ignoring few nodes?

Tags: java, json, gson

I want to compare two JsonObjects (GSON) in Java in such a way that I can ignore some predefined nodes like timestamp, id, etc.

Here is example JsonObject:

```
Object 1: 
{
   "id": "uid1",
   "name": "name",
   "data": {
          "timestamp": "timestamp1",
          "properties": {
                  "id": "propId1",
                  "propertyName": "propertyValue"
          }
   }
}

Object 2:
{
   "id": "uid2",
   "name": "name",
   "data": {
          "timestamp": "timestamp2",
          "properties": {
                  "id": "propId2",
                  "propertyName": "propertyValue"
          }
   }
}
```

In above JsonObjects the comparison should result as identical. "id" and "timestamp" should be ignored.

Since my JsonObjects are nested and complicated I am trying to find a way I could do it avoiding to iterate all nodes. Using "equals" will right now give identical as false.

Answer (score 0):

If these objects are mapped to some entity in your application, you can write a Comparator which compare the equality of two objects based on your criteria of equality

Comment: The objects are pretty dynamic and can expand to n levels. All I want to ignore is id and timestamp without having to compare specific node.